# Jitter doesn't seem to separate my points in ggplot scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to offset two points in a ggplot scatter plot made with geom_points. I tried the default `jitter` as well as my own settings, but in both cases I don't see a difference in the plot. The plot always looks like the attached image, with Brazil and Mexico quite crowded together. **What should I do differently?**[image: plot]

Here's the code I've tried:

```
     p = ggplot(morning_night, aes(x = ascent_median, y = duration_median)) + geom_point(position = "jitter", aes(color=type, shape=region, size=30))
   +geom_text(aes(label=country), hjust = 0, vjust = 1.2) 

    p = ggplot(morning_night, aes(x = ascent_median, y = duration_median)) + geom_point(position = position_jitter(w=.1, h=.1), aes(color=type, shape=region, size=30))
   +geom_text(aes(label=country), hjust = 0, vjust = 1.2)

    p = ggplot(morning_night, aes(x = ascent_median, y = duration_median)) + geom_point(position = position_jitter(w=.1, h=.3), aes(color=type, shape=region, size=30))
   +geom_text(aes(label=country), hjust = 0, vjust = 1.2)
```

Here's the data frame used for this graph:

```
country     ascent_median   duration_median type    region
Sweden      41.6            1793    morning Scandinavia
Denmark     33              1960    night   Scandinavia
Mexico      75              1877    morning LatinAmerica
Brazil      74.4            1928    night   LatinAmerica
Indonesia   41.8            1492    morning SoutheastAsia
Malaysia    48.7            2208    night   SoutheastAsia
Switzerland 64.3            2461    morning CentralEurope
Austria     67.9            2113    night   CentralEurope
```

Comment: Can you attach the sample data that you're using to create this plot?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. Whenever I replot the graph using the first command you gave I clearly see the points moving. Note, however, that the position of the geom_text is not jittered and remains the same.